# Techniques to improve accuracy of time series use case

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, accuracy, exponential-smoothing

I am working on forecasting weekly revenue of 10,000 sectors. Applied basic time series models and average RMSE(in thousands) on hold-out set (last 32 weeks) as below. 
In my view, ma12 and ETS(ANN) models seems reasonable. 

1. Please let me know techniques to reduce RMSE. 

2. Which other time series models can be tried ?

---

```
 ma4       ma8       ma12      stlf      ses       holt      ets-ANN   ets-ZZN   ets-ZZN12 linear
 18.79894  18.65662  18.78054  21.34638  19.66270  19.27242  18.17565  18.52025  20.08258  25.14404
```

---

Box Plot.

### [image: BoxPlot]

Violin plot.
[image: ViolinPlot]

---

Update (Plot for two sample sectors)
[image: Sector1]
[image: Sector2]

Answer (score 1):

> In my view, ma12 and ETS(ANN) models seems reasonable.

Judging by the plots all your models have equal quality, statistically identical.

> 2. Which other time series models can be tried ?

Not sure if you have tried ARIMA. It's also not clear how exactly you applied the linear model.

After looking at raw data charts:

I think you could try more steps on top of what you have done:

- Replace values that show a clear pattern of being out of the line
  with the rest of the time series with mean/median of neighbours. This
  may (bot not must) improve a model quality.
- Combine all you data together (take average all
  over the sales points for each week). Apply very detailed `auto.arima` to this one
  meta series, or, even better, build a model manually. It can be that
  one model (one set of ARIMA params) will serve well for all of your
  time series.

In order to deal with different scales of sales for different points, I would do this: for each time series take `x_diff == diff(log(X))`, than take `mean(x_diff )` across all series, and then restore original scale.

- Make a better decision of whether your linear model is additive or
  multiplicative. It may be that the variance in different years is
  strongly not constant, thus additive model (`lm(y ~ t + s)`) may work
  poorly.
- Maybe you want to smooth the time series by applying a running mean
  window in order to deal with outliers.

Comment: ARIMA - I tried auto.arima() and it takes lot of time when I loop with many time series.

Comment: Linear -  tslm(training_data ~ trend + season).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Could you add to yur question a plot of one of your time series (rescaled if you want to preserve anonimity) where you would indicate train and test parts? Without getting closer look at the data it is hard to recommend better methods.

Comment: Wow. Looks like you got strong seasonality for one week in a year only (january). eye-analysis suggests that you can also have changing seasonal pattern: two years january extra low, one year - extra high. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Aljo Jose, I suggest that you try running ANOVA where factor is the model that you have already tried, and the response is squared residuals. It is a basic step to understand whether your mean residuals by model differ significantly.